# Creating an interactive semicircle navigation with HTML and Css

Tags: html, css

i want to create an interactive wiki with html & css by using a semicircle and dividing the circle into different pieces for each topic. I had the following draft in mind:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Oqp.png

I haven't done html and css in the context of creating own SVGs with animations. 
Currently i am using [this example](https://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/d8c61395575a99ae2fe9de8043ef8e66) as a starting point:

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="one">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">Category 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon">Category 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="three">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="icon"> Category 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="sector">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" class="sector" d="M0.5,0.5 l0.5,0 A0.5,0.5 0 0,0 0.75,.066987298 z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

```css
$base: #A5E2F3;

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 70%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  .menu {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  .menu {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
.menu li { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  clip-path: url(#sector);
  /* try this one in Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  /* clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 75% 6.6%); */

  a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover {
    background-color: gold;
  }
}
.one {
  background-color: $base;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.two {
  background-color: darken($base, 7%);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.three {
  background-color: darken($base, 14%);
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  /* exact values here depend on what you are placing inside the items (icon, image, text, etc.) */
  right: 15%;
  top: 30%;
  /* make sure it it rotated enough; angle of rotation = angle of the sector itself */
  transform: rotate(60deg);

  /* style further as needed */
  color: darken($base, 60%);
  font-family: Indie Flower;
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

These are my question about this task: 
1) How can i create interactive buttons 
    - click on the button will make the remaining buttons disappear 
    - 1/3 semicircle will expand to a 1/4 semicicircle 
2) How can i improve the clicks with animations 
    - Button Grows from 1/3 to 1/4 semicircle

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this might help you https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/WvNQpG

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only a `<li>` can be a child of `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1). An interactive button can be created in many ways, personally I would do something like this in HTML:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="menuItem">Toggle</button>
```

and then in JavaScript (using jQuery) you can check for when this button is clicked:

```
$("button[data-toggle='menuItem']").on("click", function () {
    // - Do your toggle logic in here
    // - Do '.hide()' on all buttons that aren't '$(this)'.
    // - Add class to '$(this)' to make it expand.
});
```

2). It really depends on how you're creating your semi-circles but I would say your best cross-browser solution would be to look into the CSS 'transition' property a bit more: [W3Schools CSS transition Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)

I hope this helps, let me know if you don't understand something I've said.